# Raising the elasticity of substitution in an economy

Tags: economic-growth, elasticity, elasticity-of-substitution, ces-function

Papers such as de la Grandville (1989) and Klump/de la Grandville (2000) have shown that a higher elasticity of substitution leads to higher economic growth. My question is, if there is a way to increase the elasticity of substitution through policy measures for a simple case of a two-input (capital and labour) CES production function.